# Varible updated before saving

Tags: javascript

I have two js files `file1.js` and `file2.js`. In `file1.js` i define a function `save()` where I am saving my data and accessing some global variables to save like this

```
function save(skip)
{
    var score = 1;
    var answer=1;
    if(!skip)
    {
        var res=get_answer()
        answer=res[0];score=res[1];
    } else {
        answer=0;score=-0.33;
    }
    var date = getDate();
    var Question_id = questionId;
    var difficulty = difficulty_level;
}
```

I have another function in `file2.js` `algo()` which I am using to update `difficulty_level`. Code is

```
function algo()
{
     // some code
     if(ans1=='0' && ans2=='0')
     {
         if(difficulty_level!=1)
         difficulty_level=difficulty_level-1;
     }
 }
```

Now i am calling these both function on click of skip button.

```
$("#CT_Skip").click(function (event) {
      save(true);
      algo();
});
```

Now my problem is I am getting updated value of `difficulty_level` in `save()` function. I tried `setTimeout()` but still getting updated value. Please help me solve this. Thank you!!!

Comment: where you define you global variable

Comment: `difficulty_level` is global variable and defined in `file1.js`

Comment: that the problem,define it on the top of page before include js file and let me know it works or not ?

Comment: Why don't you run them in the opposite order? Better still, run the first function you want to execute and send it a callback to the next function it needs to executre

Comment: Now solved my problem i declared a new variable in `save` function for `difficulty_level`